# How to define variable of unknown type global in if/else sequence?

Tags: c++, class, types, scope, definition

I have 3 classes:

```
class A
{
   //
};
class B
{
   //
};
class C
{
   //
};
```

How can I define variable q with type equal to one of this classes and make it global?

- I will need only one instance and only once.
- All of this classes have methods set() and search() that work differently for each of class.
- I get value of "a" from the command line.

For example in I will define it like this, q won't be global.

```
if (a == 1) {
    A q;
} else
if (a == 2) {
    B q;
} else
if (a == 3) {
    C q;
} else
```

Comment: That's a case where you need the preprocessor (`#ifdef`), or to work with interfaces and references (since `A`,`B` and `C` are currently unrelated..

Comment: Could you [edit your question please](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29195508/edit), to become about a bit more specific about your actual use case? Do you need only one of these global instances at runtime? More of them, but only of a specific type? Are these classes completely different by means of declared member functions and variables? Be clear about your requirements first please.

Comment: See my answer please in response. It could help if you really don't need any runtime confguration support of this feature you requested.

Comment: Finally you should be clear about the point, if you need to make that decision or either `A`, `B` or `C` at compile time, or at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to provide a common base class for A,B,C and make use of factory design pattern.

```
class A : public Base
{
};

class B : public Base
{
};

class C : public Base
{
};

class ABCFactory
{
public:
 static Base* Create(int index)
 {
    switch (index) 
    {
      case 1:
    return new A;
      case 2:
    return new B;
      case 3:
    return new C;
    };
 }
};

//example usage:
std::unique_ptr<Base> p = ABCFactory::Create(1);
```

Comment: Everything fine with your answer, despite one point: Please use a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` instead of a raw pointer and `new()`.

Comment: Yeah, at the first point I've used Base* since I've been pretty sure OP won't be able to use it - but then, I decided to write the correct version :)

Comment: I merely meant to put that in the factory class itself. But good, at least you mention it.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define variable q with type equal to one of this classes and make it global?
>
> - I will need only one instance and only once.
> - All of this classes have methods set() and search() that work differently for each of class.

In this case you can consider to use the preprocessor to achieve this via compile time configuration of your program

```
#define CHOOSE_CLASS 1 // Or use -D option for the compiler in the build system
#if (CHOOSE_CLASS == 1)
A q;
#else
#if (CHOOSE_CLASS == 2)
B q;
#else 
#if (CHOOSE_CLASS == 3)
C q;
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Or a template class wrapper to select one of them

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

enum TypeSelector {
    CLASS_A ,
    CLASS_B ,
    CLASS_C ,
};

template <TypeSelector selection>
struct SelectFinal {
     typedef void FinalType;
};

template<>
SelectFinal<CLASS_A> {
     typedef A FinalType;
};

template<>
SelectFinal<CLASS_B> {
     typedef B FinalType;
};

template<>
SelectFinal<CLASS_C> {
     typedef C FinalType;
};

SelectFinal<CLASS_A>::FinalType q;
```

If you need to choose the class type at runtime, you want to go for the factory pattern as described in the other answer. Maybe with a slight modification:

```
class ABCFactory {
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Base> Create(int index) {
        static std::shared_ptr<Base> theInstance;
        if(!theInstance.get()) {
             switch (index) {
             case 1:
                 theInstance = std::make_shared<A>();
                 break;
             case 2:
                 theInstance = std::make_shared<B>();
                 break;
             case 3:
                 theInstance = std::make_shared<C>();
                 break;
             }
         }
         return theInstance;
     }
 };
```